# Binary Search Tree, Determining to use Predecessor or Successor to make tree Balanced

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm fairly new to programming in python and I wanted to make a Binary Search Tree with some implementation. My last implementation I want to add is that when the user selects my 'delete' function, whatever item they want deleted, my function will come up with the best number to replace it with. Either the successor or the predecessor, in order to make my tree balanced.
               [image]

So in this example, the user wants '30' to be deleted. So what would you replace it with? I want my program to replace it with the '24' to make the list more balanced due to the number of nodes '24' has compared to the '52' on the other side. However, it will randomly select one which would make 45 take over 30 which I do not want.

Here is my TreeNode class:

```
class TreeNode(object):

    def __init__(self, data = None, left=None, right=None):
        self.item = data
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.item)
```

This is my main function, I trimmed most of it besides my delete function and my count function which could make the process easier I would think.

```
from TreeNode import TreeNode


class BST(object):

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def __init__(self):

        """create empty binary search tree
        post: empty tree created"""

        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def delete(self, item):

        """remove item from binary search tree
        post: item is removed from the tree"""

        self.root = self._subtreeDelete(self.root, item)

    #------------------------------------------------------------

    def _subtreeDelete(self, root, item):

        if root is None:   # Empty tree, nothing to do
            return None
        if item < root.item:                             # modify left
            root.left = self._subtreeDelete(root.left, item)
        elif item > root.item:                           # modify right
            root.right = self._subtreeDelete(root.right, item)
        else:                                            # delete root
            if root.left is None:                        # promote right subtree
                root =  root.right
            elif root.right is None:                     # promote left subtree
                root = root.left
            else:
                # root node can't be deleted, overwrite it with max of 
                #    left subtree and delete max node from the subtree
                root.item, root.left = self._subtreeDelMax(root.left)
        return root

 def _subtreeDelMax(self, root):

        if root.right is None:           # root is the max 
            return root.item, root.left  # return max and promote left subtree
        else:
            # max is in right subtree, recursively find and delete it
            maxVal, root.right = self._subtreeDelMax(root.right)
            return maxVal, root  

 def treeSize(self, root, size = 0):

        if root is None:
            return -1

        if root is not None:
            self.size += 1
            if root.left is not None:
                self.treeSize(root.left, size)
            if root.right is not None:
                self.treeSize(root.right, size)
        return self.size
```

If anyone could help me on how I could change my delete function in order to make it search for the right node to delete. Thanks!

EDIT: I don't know if this helps but here is my test code also:

```
from BinarySearchTree import BST
from TreeNode import TreeNode

tree = TreeNode(4, TreeNode(2, TreeNode(1), TreeNode(3)), TreeNode (7, TreeNode(6),TreeNode(9, TreeNode(8), TreeNode(10))))

a = BST()



print("PRE-ORDER TRANSVERSE:")
print(a.preOrder(tree))
print("IN-ORDER TRANSVERSE:")
print(a.inOrder(tree))
print("POST-ORDER TRANSVERSE:")
print(a.postOrder(tree))


print("There are,", a.treeSize(tree),"nodes in this tree.")
```

So basically for my test it needs to replace the '30' with the '24'.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not my preferred language so I will not try to engage at that level, but at a theoretical level I would suggest looking at the possibility having your nodes be aware of the height of each sub-tree.

So any time you add a node you are obviously moving down through the tree to insert, when you return up the tree you can have a value indicate if the height was increased and track it at each level.  Then when you delete you can easily grab the sub-tree with the greatest height, or when equal just always take the left one (for instance).